# $("#container").css("left") - what is the expected behaviour?

Tags: jquery, css

`$("#container").css("left")` should return the left positioning of an element. If the css for the element says `left: 20px;` the jQuery should return `20px`. What should happen for an element that is positioned relative, but not given a CSS `left` position?

I've noticed that Chrome and Firefox handle this differently. Firefox returns `0px`, Chrome returns `auto`. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tR8QY/1/) to provide a demo of the behaviour. Please view it in Firefox and Chrome.

Is this expected behaviour? To me it looks like Chrome and FF give the element a different default position (`0px`/`auto`). Is there a standard that applies in this case, that one of the browsers is violating, and if so, which one is correct?

Comment: If you didn't defined the position then it will return as generated in user agent

Comment: IE also gives "auto", incidentally.

Comment: jQuery's `.css()` uses `getComputedStyle()`. The [DOM 2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html) for `getComputedStyle()` references the old CSS2 definition of "computed value" which is very different from the current CSS2.1 definition, which makes it pretty confusing. [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-window-getcomputedstyle) instead calls this return value the *resolved* value instead of the computed value, which is somewhat closer to the term "used value", although note that the expected implementation doesn't change and neither does the name of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The default for left is "auto"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp)

Comment: Please use another article, such as the [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/left) or [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left), or the [official W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props), for `left` (and other items), as [W3Schools is not always reliable](http://www.w3fools.com/). Since `left` is a relatively trivial property, this isn't as big of a deal, but for other web technologies it can make quite a difference.